# Flash Builder: How to refresh datagrid data?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

I am trying to refresh the datagrid to reflect the updated data after the user updates the database. Is that possible? I have the following code:

script

```
protected function updataHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   updateJobsResult.token = Service.updateJobs(updateJobData);
   //The database will be updated after users click the update button
   //I want to update datagrid dataprovider to show the updated data.

}


<s:datagrid dataprovider="jobdata">
//jobdata comes from from database query
..................
..................

</datagrid>

<s:form>
//when user selects the row in datagrid, the cell values will 
//pop in this form and user can update the form
.................
.................
</form>

<s:button click="updateHandler">
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just refresh the dataProvider **jobdata** when service responds successfully (you don't want to update the View before in case the server throws an error). If you tag it with `[Bindable]` the datagrid will auto update immediately.

You can also replace individual items directly in the dataProvider if you prefer using a unique identifier if available.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. after update the database, you can retrieve the data again and
   assign it to the dataprovider.
2. when you send a update request to the database, you also update the dataprovider directly.